# Gmail API - Send email with signature

Tags: vb.net, gmail-api, signature

First, I apologize for my bad writing of English.

I'm new to the Gmail API, and I'm currently blocked from sending an email with my default signature from my Gmail account.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
Dim MySmtp As SmtpClient = New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
Dim MyMail As MailMessage = New MailMessage()

        Try
            '***********************
            MySmtp.UseDefaultCredentials = False
            MySmtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
            MySmtp.EnableSsl = True
            MySmtp.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("XXXXX@gmail.com", "XXXX")


            MyMail.From = New MailAddress("XXXXX@gmail.com", "XXXXXXXXXXXXX")
            MyMail.To.Add("YYYYYYYYYYY@gmail.com")


            MyMail.IsBodyHtml = True
            MyMail.Subject = "test"
            MyMail.Body = "test body"

            ' MySmtp.SendAsync(MyMail, "tes")

            MySmtp.Send(MyMail)

         
            '****************

        Catch ex As Exception
         
        End Try
```

Unfortunately, the email sent does not include my signature by default.

I understood that the signature was attached to the web account of the email address and not to the delegate email.

But how can I add my signature to this email?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: “*how can I add my signature to this email?*” Why not just add it to the body…?

Comment: It's complicated for me to add it inside the body directly because it is preformatted to contain a lot of images,  Link to Google Maps, email, phone...

Comment: Ok, regardless of how much content is there or how it's formatted there must be HTML markup driving it all that you can literally just hard code into the body string you're building, no? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

To add your signature from Gmail, you will need to use the `Gmail API` to send the email instead of the `SmtpClient` class.

Here is an example for you:

```
// Create a new Gmail service and authenticate with the Gmail API
var gmailService = new GmailService();
gmailService.Authenticate("XXXXX@gmail.com", "XXXX");

// Create a new email message
var message = new Message
{
    Subject = "test",
    Payload = new MessagePart
    {
        // Set the body of the email and include the default Gmail signature
        Body = new Body
        {
            Data = "test body\n\n" + gmailService.Users.Settings.SendAs.Get("me", "XXXXX@gmail.com").Signature,
            Size = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount("test body\n\n" + gmailService.Users.Settings.SendAs.Get("me", "XXXXX@gmail.com").Signature)
        }
    },
    // Set the recipient(s) of the email
    To = new List<string>
    {
        "YYYYYYYYYYY@gmail.com"
    }
};

// Send the email
gmailService.Users.Messages.Send(message, "me").Execute();
```

the `GmailService.Users.Settings.SendAs.Get` method is used to retrieve the default signature for the Google account. This signature is then included in the body of the email using the `Message.Payload.Body property`.

For more info, please refer to https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings.sendAs/